# Update UILabel via Timer not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to update a UILabel that is counting down from the users birthdate to a later date. I'm trying to update the label so they can see it counting down but can't seem to get it working. Advice is appreciated!

Here's where I make the timer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeFormatted:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

and here is where I get the actual count down information...

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds
{       
    NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval = [self numberOfSecondsToLive];

    NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval sinceDate:date1]; 

    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];

  _numberofSeconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %dyears:%dMonths:%ddays:%dhour:%dminutes:%dseconds",[conversionInfo year],[conversionInfo month], [conversionInfo day], [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo minute], [conversionInfo second]];

    [date1 release];
    [date2 release];
 }
```

What happens is that it does show the correct countdown information, but it doesn't update it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You started the timer with `repeats:NO` you want that to be `repeats:YES` to have the timer repeat.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this and thought it would be something simple that I missed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want to set `repeats` to `YES` instead of `NO` in this line:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeFormatted:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

On a side note, this line is wrong:

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds
```

It should be:

```
- (void)timeFormatted:(NSTimer *)timer
```